# Frame resolution settings in gstreamer pipeline

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, resolution, screen-resolution, gst-launch

I am streaming my laptop screen on my IP based display using gstreamer.

Here is the pipeline on both ends:

Laptop:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v dx9screencapsrc ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264,profile=baseline" ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=<ipaddr> port=5004 sync=true
```

IP Display:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! vpudec low-latency=true ! imxv4l2sink sync=false
```

The problem is Display resolution is 1024x768 but the source plugin is generating 1920x1080, which is my laptop resolution..

I need to convert this to the resolution of IP Display, I modified the pipeline on the laptop to following:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v dx9screencapsrc  ! video/x-raw, width=1024,height=768,framerate=30/1 !queue ! videoconvert  ! x264enc  ! "video/x-h264,profile=baseline" ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=<IPAddress> port=5004 sync=true
```

It fails with the following error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link dx9screencapsrc0 to queue0, dx9screencapsrc0 can't handle caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1024, height=(int)768, framerate=(fraction)30/1
```

Looking at the caps of dx9screencapsrc using gst-inspect-1.0, it has cap for width and height.

How can I acheive my requirement of capturing the whole screen but converting it to 1024x768

Comment: Did you have look at dx9screencapsrc plugin properties you can specify x/y/width/height.

Comment: Those are window specific capture width and height, I need to capture the whole window, but frame resolution should be 1024x768

Comment: Then you might want to use videobox (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videobox.html) / videocrop (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videocrop.html) plugin.

Comment: I used VideoBox it didn't worked, it cropped the frames.. C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v dx9screencapsrc  ! videobox autocrop=true ! "video/x-raw, width=1024,height=768" ! queue   ! videoconvert  ! x264enc  ! "video/x-h264,profile=baseline" ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=<IP> port=5004 sync=true

Comment: ahh you could use videoscale plugin (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-videoscale.html) this shouldn’t crop.

Comment: I used videoscale plugin, the caps did show 1024,768 but the Display is not full screen.

Comment: add "  ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1024,height=768" before your imxv4l2sink

Comment: Added.. But the same effect, it is not full screen.

Comment: should be issue with imxv4l2sink, try displaying some video locally and see if you get full screen!

Comment: Playing video locally will get full screen

Comment: did you add " ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1024,height=768" before your imxv4l2sink before playing video locally ?

Comment: No i didn't add